# How to set filter value by parameter field in tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I've created a parameter A and calculated field B to choose filter (between C and D) based on A.
How can I set filter value, when make a choice in B?
Something like:

```
    IF B==C then C = 'enabled'
    IF B==D then D = 12
```

Field C and D have different dimensions, so, making choice in B and then switching to another value
I got an empty dashboard before setting any value in the filter.

When I choose Year to date filter and switch to ENABLE I see my plots, but when changing to By month option nothing selected, and to fix any visualization I need to choose values again. When I switch Year to date this story returns.

[When I choose Year to date filter and switch to ENABLE I see my plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKdVm.png)

[but when changing to By month option nothing selected, and to fix any visualization I need to choose values again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xcp4.png)

[This is the way how I calculate the chosen filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/locAh.png)

Comment: can you please show this through sample data.  I am unable to understand what are C and D?

Comment: Still I am not able to get it.  Meanwhile you can have a look at this https://www.flerlagetwins.com/2020/10/dynamically-change-your-drop-down-menus.html.  may be this can solve your problem.  Or if you can please upload your workbook.

Comment: Please also show me the calculation used in calculated field B

Comment: @AnilGoyal please find it attached

Comment: with your given screenshots, I am not able understand your data structure.  May be you can upload some sample data, codes used for parameters, etc.  Largely your problem doesn't seen complicated but I cannot solve it with your names A, B, C and D.  Out of these what are fields, what are field values? Or if your data is sensitive enough to share, at least re-phrase your problem on sample superstore data